# Как сделать пробел в php

Tags: php

Всех с Новым годом !
Прошу помощи, не силён в PHP
Подскажите как сделать пробел в данном коде PHP, нужно между параметрами сделать пробел

'.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"],$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'

Если можно, подскажите пример
Заранее спасибо !

```
<div class="board-view-price price-currency" >
          '.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"],$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'
          '.$Main->adOutCurrency($param["data"]["ads_price"], $param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'
        </div>




 function price($float=0, $currency_code="", $abbreviation_million=false){
    global $config, $settings;

    $ULang = new ULang();

    if( !$settings["abbreviation_million"] ){
        $abbreviation_million = false;
    }

    if( $currency_code ){
       $currency = $settings["currency_data"][ $currency_code ]["sign"];
    }else{
       $currency = $settings["currency_main"]["sign"];
    }

    $float_format = number_format($float,1,".",",");

    if( $abbreviation_million == false ){

        if( intval(explode(".", $float_format )[1]) == 0 ){
           return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
        }else{
           if( strpos($float_format, ",") === false ){
              return number_format($float,1,$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
           }else{
              return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
           }
        }

    }else{
        
        if( $float >= 1000000 && $float <= 9999999 ){
            
            if( substr($float, 1,1) != 0 ){
               return substr($float, 0,1).','.substr($float, 1,1).' '.$ULang->t("млн") .' '.$currency;
            }else{
               return substr($float, 0,1).' '. $ULang->t("млн") .' '.$currency;
            }

        }elseif( $float >= 10000000 && $float <= 99999999 ){
            return substr($float, 0,2).' '. $ULang->t("млн") .' '.$currency;
        }elseif( $float >= 100000000 && $float <= 999999999 ){
            return substr($float, 0,3).' '. $ULang->t("млн") .' '.$currency;
        }else{
            return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `'.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"].' '.$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'` ?

Comment: К сожалению данный вариант, не дает возможности поставить пробел.

Comment: Так нажми пробел и все дела. А так непонятно, что нужно сделать.

Comment: К сожалению ни пробелы ни другие манипуляции никак не раздвигают пространство между параметрами ! В этом и вся задача , что и как сделать !

Comment: сейчас так  27,000UAH, а нужно получить 27,000  UAH -- пространство между ценой и валютой

Comment: а что из этого кода выводит 27,000 и что UAH

Comment: $param["data"]["ads_price"]  --- 27.000
$param["data"]["ads_currency"] -- UAH

Comment: Нужно смотреть, что там есть в функции price() и ставить пробел там

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин данный вариант дает возможность поставить пробел. Не дает возможность ваш метод price.

Comment: в коде функции замените вхождения ` . $currency` в операторах `return` на `. "&nbsp;$currency"`

Comment: @teran Ничего не помогает, честно упал духом уже, в поиске решения

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин обновите кеш страницы, иногда допускаются прям ну очень глупые ошибки, причём всеми

Comment: ох, ну это понятно, кеш, разрешения, файлы куки . Да ничего не помогает !! Ну правда ! Может в чём то другом собака зарыта, не пойму, почему не меняется, цифры подставляеш есть результат, а пробел нет !

Comment: `return number_format($float...сократил......_sep"])."999".$currency;` - попробуйте так, там у вас 4 строки такие. Если выведет 999, тогда уж с пробелом разберетесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
function price($float=0, $currency_code="", $abbreviation_million=false){
    global $config, $settings;

    $ULang = new ULang();

    if( !$settings["abbreviation_million"] ){
        $abbreviation_million = false;
    }

    if( $currency_code ){
       $currency = $settings["currency_data"][ $currency_code ]["sign"];
    }else{
       $currency = $settings["currency_main"]["sign"];
    }
    $currency = " <span style='font-size: 14px;'>".$currency."</span>";

    $float_format = number_format($float,1,".",",");

    if( $abbreviation_million == false ){

        if( intval(explode(".", $float_format )[1]) == 0 ){
           return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
        }else{
           if( strpos($float_format, ",") === false ){
              return number_format($float,1,$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
           }else{
              return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
           }
        }

    }else{
        
        if( $float >= 1000000 && $float <= 9999999 ){
            
            if( substr($float, 1,1) != 0 ){
               return substr($float, 0,1).','.substr($float, 1,1).' '.$ULang->t("млн").$currency;
            }else{
               return substr($float, 0,1).' '. $ULang->t("млн").$currency;
            }

        }elseif( $float >= 10000000 && $float <= 99999999 ){
            return substr($float, 0,2).' '. $ULang->t("млн").$currency;
        }elseif( $float >= 100000000 && $float <= 999999999 ){
            return substr($float, 0,3).' '. $ULang->t("млн") .$currency;
        }else{
            return number_format($float,$config["number_format"]["decimals"],$config["number_format"]["dec_point"],$config["number_format"]["thousands_sep"]).$currency;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: можно было `$currency = " $currency";` сделать перед всем этим один раз, а не 8 раз код менять

Comment: sousage1212   !!! Получилось по вашему предоставленному коду ! ОГОРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ !! Если можно подскажите как теперь в этом коде изменить font-size у названия валюты ? через css. В этом коде только можно изменить, больше нигде ! С уважением к Вам

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин Попробуйте, поправил

Comment: sousage1212
  Огромное СПАСИБО !!! ВСЁ СУПЕР !!!! Вы решили эту головоломку !! С уважением к Вам !!!!

Comment: Добрый день. Всё было хорошо пока не обнаружил что  $currency = " <span style='font-size: 14px;'>".$currency."</span>";  выводится информация стиля   вместе с суммой 
Пример:  Город, Товар №3, цена: 10,000 <span style='font-size: 14px;'>ГРН</span>

Подскажите а можно по другому каким нибудь способом сделать стиль у суммы?

Comment: Эта проблема обнаружилась в заголовке вкладки браузера и при поделится кнопки соц сетей.

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин можно сделать разными способами. В вашем случае надо анализировать, почему это происходит и оттуда уже придумывать решение

Comment: Скорее всего нужно в этом коде изменять стиль, так как он обвернутый div 
<div class="board-view-price price-currency" >
          '.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"],$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'&nbsp;
          '.$Main->adOutCurrency($param["data"]["ads_price"], $param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'
        </div>
Но как это сделать знаний нехватает

Answer (score 0):

Довольно странно, что для Вас не работает метод @sousage1212. Но Вы можете использовать html тег: `&nbsp` он добавить дополнительный пробел.
Итоговый код:

```html
<div class="board-view-price price-currency" >
          '.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"],$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'&nbsp;
          '.$Main->adOutCurrency($param["data"]["ads_price"], $param["data"]["ads_currency"]).'
        </div>
```

P.S проверьте поддержку этого тега в браузерах!

Comment: Нет, это не работает.   '.$Main->price($param["data"]["ads_price"] пробел ,$param["data"]["ads_currency"]).' пробел должен быть внутри строки, так же неразрывный пробел внутри не помогает

Comment: @АндрейЧеремушкин вы содержимое метода price скиньте уже, чтобы люди не играли в экстрасенсов. Все методы, что вам дали - рабочие на 100%. Что у вас там в методе творится, известно лишь вам.

Comment: Прикрепил function price